# SQL Server show only rows (all columns) with a distinct column name

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have a query which produces several results. I have concatenated several columns into 1 as an ID. I only want to show the rows where the ID is unique.

The below image is an example of my table:

[image]

As you can see the ID is repeated a few times. How can I construct a query to show only the 3 unique rows?

Nesting this query and using `distinct(RowID)` shows the three rows but I cannot show the rest of the columns?

Any ideas welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use distinct in the select for all columns

Query:

```
select distinct RowID, OrderNum, cDescription, Thickness, UllTimberThickness, Width, UllTimberWidth, Length
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT RowID, OrderNum, cDescription, Thickness, etcetera ...
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY RowID, OrderNum, cDescription, Thickness, etcetera ...
```

( etcetera is a placeholder for the rest of your columns )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t1
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable t2
    where t2.id = t1.id) = 1
```

In this way, you get all rows where id is unique. I write this query because I don't know if at your ID other fields are the same, because you have built your field with a set of information. If all the columns are the same for equal id so you can use the statement DISTINCT as adviced you by Vasanth Sundaralingam in his post.

Comment: Please add some kind of clarification/justification for this answer

Comment: Ok, I've integrated my solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by what "get the three unique rows means".

If you mean rows that are unique, use `count(*)` as a window function:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

If you mean one example of each row, use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             row_number(*) over (partition by id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```